# Software keyboard resizes background image on Android

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

Whenever the software keyboard appears, it resizes the background image. Refer to the screenshot below:

[image]

As you can see, the background is sort of squeezed. Anyone can shed a light on why the background resizes?

My Layout is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/page_bg"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    >
        <EditText android:id="@+id/CatName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:lines="1"
        />
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:onClick="saveCat"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/add_totalk"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/add_small"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:onClick="createToTalk"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Ok I fixed it by using

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```

entry inside `<Activity >` tag in `manifest` file. I think it was caused by having ScrollView inside the Activity.

Comment: The problem is that scrolling is, when using adjustPan, not working... (if you have a ScrollView), and thats annoying...

Comment: But the scrollview is not working now. is thr any way to avoid it

Comment: I need scroll view. Do you have a way to keep the scroll view and keep the background un compressed.

Comment: That's not enough. At least, if you don't use a ScrollView. Much better is a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29750860/2914140 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/18191266/2914140.

Comment: `stateVisisble` made my keyboard automatically pop up, so I just used `adjustPan` and still worked for me.

Comment: if you don't want to display keyboard automatically then use : android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: This solution worked kinda but caused other issues...using the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16917160/1815624 which worked better for me.

Comment: I used both stateVisible|adjustPan but the background still moves after the keyboard appears/hides. My main layout is a scrollview though

Comment: Needs to be in activity tag, won't work if it's in application tag.

Comment: Also ```stateVisible``` causes the keyboard to show onCreate. I removed that tag and just used ```adjustPan```

Answer (score 114):

I faced the same problem while developing a chat app, chat screen with a background image. `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` squeezed my background image to fit the available space after the soft keyboard was displayed and "adjustPan" shifted the whole layout up to adjust the soft keyboard.
The solution to this problem was setting the window background instead of a layout background inside an activity XML. Use **`getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable()`** in your activity.

Comment: Very good! Best answer! adjustPan causes collateral effects like: The keyboard overrides components but no scrollbar are displayed.

Comment: @parulb or anyone else that happens to read this, this works great (and thank you for it) as long as the background image doesn't contain relevant information. The problem I encounter from time to time is that my background will contain something like a logo, and setting the window background to the image hides the logo behind the ActionBar. For certain screens this isn't an issue, but sometimes I am required to keep the ActionBar (no hiding). Any ideas on how to handle some sort of padding while setting the window background to take the ActionBar into account?

Comment: What if i am having a fragment how to deal with it ? its not working for fragments

Comment: To user2056563: For fragments just use getActivity().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable() or getActivity().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource()

Comment: Thank you, it worked even with scrollview. I did like this on new AppCompat: getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.background));

Comment: This shoud be the right answeir! Adjust pan narrows your abilities to code (you can not use ither options - like adjust resize, ets). We showd only set background to activities window, in all chat apps

Comment: What to do if I want to use scale type in this? Because for notch screen image is stretching.

Answer (score 39):

Here is the best solution to avoid such kind of problem.

**Step 1:** Create a style

```
<style name="ChatBackground" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_chat</item>
</style>
```

**Step 2:** Set your activity style in the `AndroidManifest` file

```
<activity
    android:name=".Chat"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/ChatBackground" >
```

Comment: nice! simplest solution

Comment: Excellent solution,esp because it doesn't use the `windowSoftInputMode` which only brings more issues!

Comment: you are a genius !

Answer (score 32):

Through  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  giving bad user experience because through that entire screen goes on top (shift to top ) So, following is one of the best answeres.

I have same Problem  but after that , i Found Awesome answeres from the @Gem

**In Manifest**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"
```

**In xml**

Dont Set any background here and keep your view under ScrollView

**In Java**

You need to set the background to window:

```
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.bg_wood) ;
```

Thanks to @Gem.

Comment: Thanks for the recognition.

Comment: What to do if I want to use scale type in this? Because for notch screen image is stretching.

Answer (score 14):

just for addition...

if u have a listview on your activity
u need to add this `android:isScrollContainer="false"` in your listview properties...

and don't forget to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in your manifest xml at your activity...

if you guys using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustUnspecified"` with scrollable view on your layout, then your background will still resized by the soft keyboard...

it would be better if you use "adjustPan" value to prevent your background from resizing...

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" make the whole view shift with keyboard. Generally we have a title of the screen on the top. Using this flag it will also go out of the visible area, which make bad user experience.

Comment: @Gem : so what's the solution ?

Comment: @Copernic I faced this problem long time back when i was working on a chat application. Eventually i fixed that please refer my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307264/how-to-prevent-soft-keyboard-from-resizing-background-image/23651818#23651818

Answer (score 7):

In case if somebody need an `adjustResize` behavior and don't want his `ImageView` to be resized here is another workaround.

Just put `ImageView` inside `ScrollView` => `RelativeLayout` with `ScrollView.fillViewport = true`.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/gift_checked" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This is a good solution in case u have other Views in the background other than an image....Thanks

Answer (score 6):

After studying and implementing all available answers, here I am adding a solution.

This answer is combination of code from:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45620231/1164529

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27702210/1164529

Here is the custom `AppCompatImageView` class which showed no stretching or scrolling w.r.t. soft keyboard:-

```
public class TopCropImageView extends AppCompatImageView {

    public TopCropImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    public TopCropImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    public TopCropImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        computeMatrix();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        computeMatrix();
        return super.setFrame(l, t, r, b);
    }


    private void computeMatrix() {
        if (getDrawable() == null) return;
        Matrix matrix = getImageMatrix();
        float scaleFactor = getWidth() / (float) getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        matrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, 0, 0);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }
}
```

To use it as background to my `Fragment` class, I set it as first element to `FrameLayout`.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <complete.package.TopCropImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/my_app_background" />

    <!-- Enter other UI elements here to overlay them on the background image -->

<FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the easy answer :) you save my time

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the main problem when working on my app. At first, I use the method provided by @parulb to solve the problem. Thank him a lot. But later I noticed that the background image is partially hided by actionbar (and statusbar I am sure). This small issue is already proposed by @zgc7009 who commented below the answer of @parulb one year and a half ago but no one replied.

I worked a whole day to find out a way and fortunately I can at least solve this problem perfectly on my cellphone now.

First we need a layer-list resource in drawable folder to add padding on the top to the background image:

```
<!-- my_background.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="75dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/bg" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Second we set this file as resource for background as mentioned above:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.my_background);
```

I am using Nexus 5. I found a way to get height of actionbar in xml but not the statusbar, so I have to use a fixed height 75dp for top padding. Hope anyone can find the last piece of this puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

I suffered similar issues, but it seems like using `adjustPan` with `android:isScrollContainer="false"` still didn't fix my layout (which was a RecyclerView below a LinearLayout). The RecyclerView was fine, but every time the virtual keyboard showed up, the LinearLayout re-adjusted.

To prevent this behavior (I simply wanted to have the keyboard go over my layout), I went with the following code:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".librarycartridge.MyLibraryActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" />
```

This tells Android to basically leave your layout alone when the virtual keyboard is called.

More reading about possible options can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) (though oddly enough, it doesn't seem like there's an entry for `adjustNothing`).

Answer (score 2):

Add this line in **AndroidManifest.xml** file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode=adjustUnspecified
```

refer to [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) for more info.

Comment: It's still happening even after I did this. This is getting frustrating :(

Answer (score 2):

I faced with this problem, when my background image was just a `ImageView` inside a `Fragment`, and it was resized by the keyboard.

My solution was: using custom `ImageView` from [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29783482/6264830), edited to be compatible with `androidx`.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView;

/**
 * Created by chris on 7/27/16.
 */
public class TopCropImageView extends AppCompatImageView {

    public TopCropImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    public TopCropImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    public TopCropImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        recomputeImgMatrix();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        recomputeImgMatrix();
        return super.setFrame(l, t, r, b);
    }

    private void recomputeImgMatrix() {
        if (getDrawable() == null) return;

        final Matrix matrix = getImageMatrix();

        float scale;
        final int viewWidth = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
        final int viewHeight = getHeight() - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();
        final int drawableWidth = getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        final int drawableHeight = getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

        if (drawableWidth * viewHeight > drawableHeight * viewWidth) {
            scale = (float) viewHeight / (float) drawableHeight;
        } else {
            scale = (float) viewWidth / (float) drawableWidth;
        }

        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }

}
```

Comment: It don't stretch anymore with above code but it still scrolls a little up/down w.r.t. soft keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to substitute the background of the window with the one of the layout, then set the layout background to null. In this way I keep the image in the XML preview window:

So keep the background in the layout and add an id for it. 
Then in the activity onCreate() put this code:

```
    ConstraintLayout mainLayout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(mainLayout.getBackground());
    mainLayout.setBackground(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same problem before but no solution worked for me so long because i was using a `Fragment`, and also
`getActivity().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable()`  was not a solution for me.

Solution which worked for me is to override `FrameLayout` with a logic to handle keyboard which should appear and change the bitmap on the go.

Here is my FrameLayout code (Kotlin):

```
class FlexibleFrameLayout : FrameLayout {

    var backgroundImage: Drawable? = null
        set(bitmap) {
            field = bitmap
            invalidate()
        }
    private var keyboardHeight: Int = 0
    private var isKbOpen = false

    private var actualHeight = 0

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : super(context, attributeSet) {
        init()
    }

    fun init() {
        setWillNotDraw(false)
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        val height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)
        if (actualHeight == 0) {
            actualHeight = height
            return
        }
        //kb detected
        if (actualHeight - height > 100 && keyboardHeight == 0) {
            keyboardHeight = actualHeight - height
            isKbOpen = true
        }
        if (actualHeight - height < 50 && keyboardHeight != 0) {
            isKbOpen = false
        }
        if (height != actualHeight) {
            invalidate()
        }
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        if (backgroundImage != null) {
            if (backgroundImage is ColorDrawable) {
                backgroundImage!!.setBounds(0, 0, measuredWidth, measuredHeight)
                backgroundImage!!.draw(canvas)
            } else if (backgroundImage is BitmapDrawable) {
                val scale = measuredWidth.toFloat() / backgroundImage!!.intrinsicWidth.toFloat()
                val width = Math.ceil((backgroundImage!!.intrinsicWidth * scale).toDouble()).toInt()
                val height = Math.ceil((backgroundImage!!.intrinsicHeight * scale).toDouble()).toInt()
                val kb = if (isKbOpen) keyboardHeight else 0
                backgroundImage!!.setBounds(0, 0, width, height)
                backgroundImage!!.draw(canvas)
            }
        } else {
            super.onDraw(canvas)
        }
    }
}
```

And I used it as like an usual FrameLayout's background.

`frameLayout.backgroundImage = Drawable.createFromPath(path)`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just add in your activity

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.your_image_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your LinearLayout with FrameLayout and add ImageView with Background:

```
<FrameLayout>

  <ImageView 
    android:background="@drawable/page_bg"
    android:id="@+id/backgroundImage" />

  <LinearLayout>
    ....
  </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And You can set it height when you creating activity/fragment (to prevent from scaling when open keyboard). Some code in Kotlin from Fragment:

```
activity?.window?.decorView?.height?.let {
        backgroundImage.setHeight(it)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are set image as windowbackground and ui going to stuck. then there may be possibility you are uses drawable which is in single drawable folder,
if yes then you have to paste it in drawable-nodpi or drawable-xxxhdpi.