# How to prevent Soft Keyboard from resizing background image

Tags: android-layout

I have a typical `listview` with an `edittext` and a button at the bottom of the activity.

When I click onto the `edittext`, the soft keyboard appears, I am able to scroll the items in the `listview` but it re-sizes my background image.

I have tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` but no difference.

I have tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`. The image does not get squashed, the whole layout shifts upwards and I lose the title bar. I can only scroll the list if the list items exceed the layout size.

Basically, I want to maintain the title bar, retain the background image without re-sizing and allow scrolling of list items. Anyone managed to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 46):

for listview you need to use

```
android:isScrollContainer="false"
```

and add this to your activity in manifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: Meny solutions tried, finally worked this for SCROLL-VIEW. Thanks a Lot.

Comment: Thank you! Simply adding android:isScrollContainer="false" to my layout file for the layout which had popped up fixed it for me :)

Answer (score 26):

I have tried so may solutions for solving this problem. android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" will make your whole screen shift with keyboard. Generally we have a title of the screen on the top. Using this flag it will also go out of the visible area, which make bad user experience. I use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` This will resize the whole screen but it will cause the same problem @Maurice state in the question.

So here is my final solution:

**In Manifest**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"
```

**In XMl**

Dont Set any background here.And keep your view under ScrollView

**In Java**

You need to set the background to window:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.bg_wood) ;
```

Comment: +1 This is the right answer if you want your elements to resize, while your background stays as it is. This answer deserves more attention.

Comment: Oh God. I've been looking for this answer everywhere. This is the best solution EVER. Use Java not XML.

Comment: thanks man, it works with activity :) , & i just want to ask how if set background for fragment..?? when i use getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource in fragmentActivity, the whole page changes..

Comment: Works like a charm!! Just set background image in activity.

Answer (score 9):

Go to the Androidmanifest.xml and:

```
activity name="activityname" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```

Comment: But that resizes the bg image

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to prevent the soft keyboard from resizing a background image.

Use this `scaleType(matrix)` and prepare a suitable image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutchat"
  >

  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity ="clip_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

   <ImageView
        android:gravity ="clip_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/chat_bak_img"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix">
   </ImageView>

   </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <ListView
        android:id="@+id/chat"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="3dip"
        android:paddingTop="3dip"
        android:paddingRight="3dip">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/chatMsg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:maxLength="150"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendMsg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/send_withSpace"
            android:layout_weight="4"/>
    </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ehm, I think that adjustPan usually prevents the bg from resizing.

Answer (score 4):

Use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and simply wrap your background ImageView in a ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:overScrollMode="never">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> 
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:overScrollMode="never">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/myimage"
            />
    </ScrollView>

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem with imageview resize while keyboard up i have solved with manifest android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" and following is the layout example in my case

i.e frg_write_social:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frg_writeyourpost_ll_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:isScrollContainer="false"
android:scrollbars="none" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/frg_writeyourpost_rl_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/frg_writeyourpost_ll_bottum"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:minHeight="400dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/frg_writyourpost_iv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/frg_writeyourpost_ll_bottum"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Write your post"
                android:textColor="#727F8D"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <com.example.views.CustomEditText
                android:id="@+id/frg_writeyourpost_et_message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/slide_image"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:maxHeight="@dimen/slide_image"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:textSize="11sp" >
            </com.example.views.CustomEditText>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/frg_writeyourpost_tv_totalcharacter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="#727F8D"
                    android:textSize="8sp" />

                <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/frg_writeyourpost_tv_characterLeft"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="character"
                    android:textColor="#727F8D"
                    android:textSize="8sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/frg_writepost_fbtw_rggroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/frg_writepost_rb_facebook"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/fb_check_selector"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:text="@string/post_for_facebook"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="5dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/frg_writepost_rb_twitter"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/tw_check_selector"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:text="@string/post_for_twitter"/>
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

if there is possible to load image dynamically you can resize image with picaaso while load in imageview

Answer (score 1):

Use ImageView with fill_parent and centerCrop attributes in RelativeLayout. Like this;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/yazisma_arka_plan"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/messages_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"...
```

Answer (score 1):

I read a lot of answers over StackOverflow and took some from many to make my app works:

1. No `ScrollView` at all in my `activity_main.xml`
2. In `AndroidManifest.xml` added this attribute to the

   `<activity android:name=".MainActivity" ...>`

tag:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

3. In `MainActivity.java` inside `onCreate()`
   I added `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.app_bg);`

It works for me when all the other solutions I've tried didn't.
If you got up to here, I hope it'll work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Er, let me see ... pictures first!

[image: View before touched]
[image: View after touched]
The layout file act_login.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login_bkgd"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#0fff"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:listSelector="#0fff"
        android:divider="#0fff"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        />
    <!--!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-->
    <!--android:isScrollContainer="true"-->
    <!--!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/loginLogo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="35dp"
                >

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="1px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#Ffff"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:text="WELCOME"
                    android:textColor="#Ffff"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="1px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#Ffff"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/login_et_long"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:text="账号:"
                    android:textColor="#Ffff"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/loginUsername"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:hint="请输入手机号"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#F000"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/login_et_long"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:text="密码:"
                    android:textColor="#Ffff"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:hint="请输入密码"
                    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#F000"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/login_button"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/str_login"
                android:textColor="#Ffff"
                android:textSize="19sp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The related Java codes.

```
EditText etUsername, etPassword;
EditText etFocus;
ViewGroup base;
int mSelection;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    base=(ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.act_login, null);
    setContentView(base);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(base.getBackground());
    base.setBackground(null);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void initViews() {
    etUsername=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginUsername);
    etPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);

    final ViewGroup item=(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.loginItem);
    base.removeView(item);
    final View[] items=new View[item.getChildCount()];
    for(int i=0; i<item.getChildCount(); i++) items[i]=item.getChildAt(i);
    item.removeAllViews();

    ListView lv=(ListView)base.getChildAt(0);
    lv.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {
    public View getView(int i, View v, ViewGroup vg) {
        if(etFocus!=null && getCurrentFocus()!=etFocus){
            etFocus.requestFocus();
            etFocus.setSelection(mSelection);
            //etFocus=null;
        }
        return items[i];
    }
    public int getCount() {return items.length;}
    public Object getItem(int position) {return null;}
    public long getItemId(int position) {return 0;}
    });

    /*View.OnTouchListener listener=new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
            if(e.getAction()!=MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) return false;
            etFocus=(EditText)v;
            mSelection=etFocus.getSelectionEnd();
            ZZ.z("_________________ mSelection="+mSelection);
            return false;
        }
    };
    etUsername.setOnTouchListener(listener);
    etPassword.setOnTouchListener(listener);*/

    View.OnFocusChangeListener listener1=new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus){
                etFocus=(EditText)v;
                mSelection=etFocus.getSelectionStart();
                ZZ.z("_________________ mSelection="+mSelection);
            }
        }
    };
    etUsername.setOnFocusChangeListener(listener1);
    etPassword.setOnFocusChangeListener(listener1);
}
```

The AndroidManifest part.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.ActLogin"
        android:label="@string/str_login"
        android:theme="@style/myTheme"
        />
    <!--android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"-->
```

The style part.

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who aren't get it:

***double ckeck if your `xml` already has a `@drawable` setted* (this was the error for me, i was setting via android manifest but it was already setted on the root of xml)**

after that create a *theme style* with background:

```
<style name="AppThemeWBackgroundG" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_com_gradiente</item>
</style>
```

Then in your *activity on AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
<activity
   android:name=".TelaLoginFuncionario"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysVisible"
   android:theme="@style/AppThemeWBackgroundG"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
/>
```

and that's it: the activity enter in a screen with the keyboard up, resizing up the items and the background stays at normal size

Answer (score -1):

all you need to do is to set the background gravity to the top

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_image" android:gravity="top"/>
```

[Here is tutorial](http://blog.mohitkanwal.com/blog/2014/05/12/set-background-that-does-not-resize-on-soft-keyboard/)

Answer (score -2):

This code doesn't work for me:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

But this does work:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```