# Android: Background image resize on keyboard pop up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-background

I am developing an application in which the background image get shrink on keyboard pop-up. My .xml is as follows :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            /**
              Other stuff 
            */

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I searched on Google and found that, to add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```

in my manifest file. But its of no use.

**Edit :**

My Layout before key board pop up looks like :

[image: Image 1]

And after pop up like:

[image: Image 2]

Please check the difference in background image. In image 1 image is in size and in image 2 background image shrink-ed. I need the footer and background get shift upward on keyboard popup.

What I am missing or doing wrong please suggest me.

Comment: `adjustPan` should do exactly what you need (_"The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned"_), see [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html). What problem are you having with it?

Comment: why dont you put the image on the background of the scrollview ? or create an imageview without relation that fills the whole screen space and set it as the background because its a relatvielayout.

Answer (score 38):

Just use in your `onCreate()` this code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...   
 getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.your_image_resource);
...
}
```

and eliminate this line in your xml:

```
android:background="@drawable/background"
```

Read more at:

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html

Comment: Essentially repeats [Software keyboard resizes background image on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16917160), but with a bit of code and advice to remove `android:background`.

Answer (score 10):

I had faced the similar issue once, mine was solved by using the below properties in manifest use it where your activity is declared.

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

Comment: btw if you do not want the keyboard to be hidden when you activity starts you can skip `stateHidden` part

Answer (score 9):

Hey can you please try adding this

```
android:isScrollContainer="false"
```

in your **ScrollView**. It has solved my problem once. Might help u too.

Also, add this to your activity in manifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Hope it helps..!! :)

Answer (score 7):

Ok if I got your question right, you want a layout with a background and a scrollview. And when the softkeyboard pops up, you want to resize the scrollview, but keep the background at full size right?
if that's what you want than I may have found a workaround for this issue:

What you **can** do is make **2** activities.

**Activity 1:**

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent StartApp = new Intent(this, DialogActivity.class);
    startActivity(StartApp);         // Launch your official (dialog) Activity

    setContentView(R.layout.start);  // your layout with only the background 
    }
}
```

**Activity2:**

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);  // get rid of dimming
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  //get rid of title bar (if you want)

    setContentView(R.layout.dialog);  //Dialog Layout with scrollview and stuff

    Drawable d = new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK);  //make dialog transparent
    d.setAlpha(0);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    }
}
```

**start layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/test">  //your background
</LinearLayout>
```

**dialog layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"     
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <!-- All your Scrollview Items -->

            </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

start Activity:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

dialog Activity

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

**Edit:** 
To finish Activities at once use the following somewhere inside your DialogActivity (example: **override the backbutton**):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and in `onCreate()` of StartActivity:

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
    finish();
}
else {
    Intent StartApp = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
    startActivity(StartApp);
}
```

**Screenshots**!

**Normal**
[image: Normal]

**Clicked the EditText box**
[image: Clicked textbox]

**After Scrolled down** (ps: i put textbox inside scrollview thats why its gone ;)  )
[image: after scrolled down]

**I hope this will help your out ;)**

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue.

Add your outer layout background inside onCreate method as show below

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.login_bg);
```

and add your outer layout as

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#4d000000"
    ><other code></ScrollView></RelativeLayout>
```

Add  `android:layout_weight="1"` for the outer layout and don't set background in xml file
I think this helps someone

Answer (score 3):

You should move the `android:background="@drawable/background"` in an `ImageView` above `ScrollView`. When the keyboard pops up it effectivly makes the screen smaller, and having an image as background you have no control on how it is resized/cropped. 
So, assuming you want to have the image full width but keep the ascpect ratio try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >           
            /**
            Other stuff
            */
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can try different `android:scaleType` values to achive your desired effect. If you want the image to be cropped from the top instead of the default middle crop, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330084/imageview-scaling-top-crop) on how to achieve this, or try using [this](https://github.com/cesards/CropImageView) library

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"`,  you should change to `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"`. It worked for me.

Comment: I tried this but it is not working, as on search i get to know that it is due to scroll view in my layout.

Comment: Maybe because of your AndroidManifest.xml, can you copy your code of manifest and paste in here?

Answer (score 0):

Use ScrollView as Top parent. 
It will be scrolled up and down automatically when you open and close keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do like this

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    /**
              Other stuff 
            */
    >
  </RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the `adjustResize` option for the `windowSoftInputMode` setting on the `Activity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Answer (score -5):

i am using below view heirarchy and its working fine for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/rfqItemsParentScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: I am asking about background image. You did not mentioned about image and its shrinking.