# How set imageview scaletype to topCrop

Tags: android, imageview, scaletype

I'm coding android and I have a imageview. I want to set scaletype of this to topcrop.
I could find centercrop in options, but it's not my request. How do I do?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Custom Android ImageView for top-crop scaling of the contained drawable.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
* ImageView to display top-crop scale of an image view.
*
* @author Chris Arriola
*/
public class TopCropImageView extends ImageView {

public TopCropImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
}

@Override
protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    final Matrix matrix = getImageMatrix();

    float scale;
    final int viewWidth = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
    final int viewHeight = getHeight() - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();
    final int drawableWidth = getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    final int drawableHeight = getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

    if (drawableWidth * viewHeight > drawableHeight * viewWidth) {
        scale = (float) viewHeight / (float) drawableHeight;
    } else {
        scale = (float) viewWidth / (float) drawableWidth;
    }

    matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);

    return super.setFrame(l, t, r, b);
}        
}
```

https://gist.github.com/arriolac/3843346

Comment: how to implement this. i asked a question regarding this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359213/trying-to-use-custom-imageview-topcrop-in-android-but-the-the-app-stops.

Comment: @Jay it works great. Im making matrix computations in onLayout() method, which gets called in on rotation also, where setFrame doesn't.

Comment: I call super.setFrame(l, t, r, b); in the beginning or getWidth() will return 0

Answer (score 14):

I just wanted a temporary solution without excess work . Try this

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:scrollY="-100dp"
    android:id="@+id/poster"
   />
```

scrollY pulls your image up or down. Try it with different dp's and you 'll find the right size.

Comment: While this achieves the task at hand, it does not work for different screen resolutions or parent view sizes. Probably not recommended for production, as you will get unexpected results in the wild. :)

Comment: Yes, that's true i learned it the hard way. It behaves differently on various screens.

Comment: I only needed to move the image slightly and this worked perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe you need a custom Image View for this. All you have to do is set the `scaleType` to `matrix` and set a custom matrix to the `ImageView`.

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38049348/4747587

Answer (score 1):

Fixed version:

- setFrame calling asap
- not reusing Matrix -> it caused issue that when image realoaded too soon (with Picasso), the image was scaled too much

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Matrix
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView

class TopCropImageView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
) : AppCompatImageView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        scaleType = ScaleType.MATRIX
    }

    override fun setFrame(l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int): Boolean {
        super.setFrame(l, t, r, b)
        val matrix = Matrix()
        val scale: Float
        val viewWidth: Int = width - paddingLeft - paddingRight
        val viewHeight: Int = height - paddingTop - paddingBottom
        val drawableWidth: Int = drawable.intrinsicWidth
        val drawableHeight: Int = drawable.intrinsicHeight
        scale = if (drawableWidth * viewHeight > drawableHeight * viewWidth) {
            viewHeight.toFloat() / drawableHeight.toFloat()
        } else {
            viewWidth.toFloat() / drawableWidth.toFloat()
        }
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale)
        imageMatrix = matrix
        return true
    }
}
```