# Smooth slider with two (or more) images

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, imageview, android-bitmap

How I can reach such behavior with a smooth slider?

[image]

I want that first ImageView to increase his width and cover over second ImageView.

I tried three different approaches to this purpose.

First **I drew bitmap (two bitmaps combined inside one canvas) inside the canvas of one ImageView.** New position generated with ValueAnimation but it gives values with not equals intervals. During rendering the transition do jumps noticeably enough. On a good phone especially.

Second **I did my own method for generating sequence numbers without intervals** and but occurs another problem: phone cant render new bitmaps a few hundred times per second. If to do intervals jumps occur again.

Then I tried another way: **to create two ImageView and first must smooth roll out over the second.** But I can't reach the proper effect than the first picture must not stretch (image inside ImageView increased width together) but need a roll-out like on GIF.

**Code of my third the attempt:**

*In fragment*

```
val animation: Animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.scale_right)
imageView.startAnimation(animation)
imageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

*scale_right.xml*

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <scale
    android:duration="6000"
    android:fromXScale="0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="0%"
    android:pivotY="0%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: You can create custom view with overrided `onDraw(Canvas)` method to achive such behavior. If you want to make it intractable (swipe by user) you can use `ViewPager` with custom page animation

Comment: @Ufkoku No, without user's swipe. Images must move by themselves.

Comment: @Ufkoku Do you have an example with `onDraw(Canvas)` for the effect which I need?

Comment: Have you tried animations with ConstraintSet ? https://proandroiddev.com/creating-awesome-animations-using-constraintlayout-and-constraintset-part-i-390cc72c5f75

Comment: @AchrafAmil well, a very interesting way! But my main problem not resolved yet. How to reach the effect that image not scaling when ImageView will increase width but will opening by smooth slider? (like on GiF)

Comment: Maybe combining the ConstraintSet animation for image constraints change with some kind of start_crop similar to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29783358/how-set-imageview-scaletype-to-topcrop

Comment: You can use ValueAnimator inside your custom View. Animate value from 0 to 1, and in `onDraw` use this value as percentage to draw your new image. here is some example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616035/how-to-animate-a-path-on-canvas-android

Comment: @Ufkoku but how to write code correctly that image doesn't stretch?