# Android custom Imageview throws 'can't cast' exception

Tags: android

I'd like to use the ImageViewTopCrop class described in this question:

[ImageView scaling TOP_CROP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330084/imageview-scaling-top-crop)

My custom view is based on this code:

[Custom Image View class](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/doridori/AndroidUtils/master/App/src/main/java/com/doridori/lib/view/ImageViewTopCrop.java)

Here is a layout file using this custom view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_background"
android:background="#000"
android:orientation="vertical">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/details_frame"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="6">

<com.grayraven.imagetest.ImageViewTopCrop
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
    android:src="@drawable/hobbit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />

     </FrameLayout>
```

Here's how I'm trying to display it in code:

```
com.grayraven.imagetest;
```

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class DetailsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private TextView titleTextView;
    private com.grayraven.imagetest.ImageViewTopCrop imageView;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details_view);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();

    String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
    String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("imageUrl");
    titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    imageView = (com.grayraven.project1.ImageViewTopCrop) findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
```

//Exception thrown here:
//android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to com.grayraven.imagetest.ImageViewTopCrop

```
//can't go any further
}
```

}

What simple thing am I missing?

Comment: `com.grayraven.imagetest.ImageViewTopCrop` is not equals with `com.grayraven.project1.ImageViewTopCrop` you declare first path for your image but cast your widget with second path. is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are type casting with wrong class.

You used

```
com.grayraven.imagetest.ImageViewTopCrop
```

in your xml but type casting with `com.grayraven.project1.ImageViewTopCrop`

Comment: That was a typo, when this didn't work in project1 I made a test project called imagetest. 

Even when the paths are correct I get the exception.  :(

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a constructor in my custom view class.  Never mind.