# ImageView Starting on Left Side

Tags: android, imageview

I have an ImageView that is too big for my screen. I want it to start on the left side and continue outside of screen.

Right now I use

```
scaleType = "centerCrop"
```

but it's not what I want.

Right now I have

[image]

But what I want is

[image]

Any clue for me?
Thanks

**Edit**
Here's what it does with fitStart:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to do what I wanted with the use of matrix.

I reused the code from that answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6333518/5749193

But instead of going with the width, I went with the height to calculate the scaleFactor.

Hope it might help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use

```
scaleType = "fitStart"
```

see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

**EDIT**

Maybe set `adjustViewBounds = true`
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds

Comment: Still not what I expect.. I'll try with custom matrix