# How to load only part of image with Glide from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, imageview, android-glide

I have imageview, which should show only part of image (part which fits into part of screen). After user click, it will open whole image. But I can´t figure out, how to load only part of image into imageview. Problem is that Glide fits image into imageview, always.

```
Glide.with(context)
     .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
     .load(storageReference)
     .into(imageView);
```

How it is looks now. Red part is ImageView.

[image: How it is working now]

How I wish to have it.

[image: How I would like to have it]

**EDIT**

Following code will fits, but it show whole image, only only part of it and it destroy proportions.

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

[image]

Comment: You can use simpletarget to process image before updating to imageView

Comment: I updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

Add scale type in your `XML` of `ImageView`. add this  `android:scaleType="matrix"`

Comment: I think you should add marginRight and marginBottom in minus value.

Comment: android:scaleType="matrix" is solution. I had problem, that image didn´t have enought point to cover imageview on display from side to side. This can be handled by resampling image or using android:scaleY and android:scaleX.

Comment: Okay, Hope you like my solution. Add you can apply my second solution also.In that your ImageView cut from Right and Bottom and that gives you same effect that you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
Glide.with(mContext)
                .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                .load(storageReference)
                .asBitmap()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                        Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(resource, x, y, width, height);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(targetBitmap);
                    }
                });
```

Here you can resize your bitmap from Glide according to your dimensions. But make sure your provided dimensions are always smaller than the actual bitmap.

Since you are using this code in list, `Bitmap targetBitmap;` should be declared globally to reuse same bitmap object throughout the list. This will reduce RAM consumption of your app.

Read links related to cropping bitmaps if you need further clarity for the code `Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(resource, x, y, width, height);`

> Don't forget to make targetBitmap as Global, otherwise memory impact will be too high.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your Imageview

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: This will just make the image fit to ImageView without any unwanted background. But this guy wants A part of image to be displayed.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn´t seem to be solution, as you can see in my question EDIT.

Comment: did you try other scaletypes? like matrix,centercrop etc

Comment: I tried matrix (it is very close to required result, but it doesn´t fits image from side to side - there is space on left and right side) and I do not want to center, because I have to show top of image. FitStart is also not ok and rest of it is center.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your xml

```
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn´t seem to be solution, as you can see in my question EDIT.

Comment: You can also use android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank to Mohammed Atif, Patel Jaimin and [Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330084/imageview-scaling-top-crop), I end up with following solution.

```
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/ivImage"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:scaleType="matrix"/>

 Glide.with(this)
        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
        .load(storageReference)
        .asBitmap()
        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
         @Override
         public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(resource, 0, 0, resource.getWidth(), resource.getHeight());
                    ivImage.setImageBitmap(targetBitmap);

                    final Matrix matrix = ivImage.getImageMatrix();
                    final float imageWidth = ivImage.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
                    final float scaleRatio = ivImage.getWidth() / imageWidth;
                    matrix.postScale(scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
                    ivImage.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                }
            });
```