# capture activity screen with on-screen keyboard

Tags: android, screenshot, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to capture my activity's screen on android. I am using the code below:

```
View root = this.activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(root.getWidth(), root.getHeight(), Config.RGB_565);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
root.draw(c);

if (b != null && !b.isRecycled()) {
    this.screen = Bitmap.createBitmap(b);
}
```

If on-screen keyboard pops up, then I've got only visible part of my activity's window in `this.screen` and the rest is blank.

Is there any way to get my app's screenshot, including the parts, that are under on-screen keyboard?

Comment: i start showing you [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4290532/1521064) if you have problems with the screenshot being squeezed

Comment: screenshot is not squeezed. on screenshot present only that objects, which are above on-screen keyboard. everything else (i.e., objects that are under keyboard) is blank. I need to have them on the screenshot too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to dissapoint you, but this cannot be done without external aid. The keyboard is simply not a part of your application layout.

Your "outermost" view is the `DecorView`, which you are already snapping. That's as far as this technique goes.

**Edit**: I can't try it now, but give this a go:

```
View topmost = ((ViewGroup)
     ctx.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
).getChildAt(0);

topmost.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

Bitmap screenshot = topmost.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: You mean that I cannot capture objects that are under on-screen keyboard? In that case, what you mean when saying external aid? Also, I don't need to capture keyboard, just anything, that is on my window, even if it is under something.

Comment: can't say now, but seems that I cannot find that method. is it View's method?

Comment: My bad: `DrawingCache`. Will edit and give you an example to try. Sorry I don't do it myself, but I don't have an Android dev setup here.

Comment: now screenshot is trimmed. I'm testing on a galaxy tab 2, with my code, I was getting an image 1024x600 with a blank part, where is on-screen keyboard and now I'm getting an 1024x173 image. So, result is the same, I cannot get object, that are placed under on-screen keyboard.