# EditText forcing ActionBar to hide

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview, android-actionbar

An `EditText` at the bottom of a `ListView` when pressed, hides the `ActionBar`. My first problem was to prevent the background image of `ListView` to shrink. Somehow i overcame my issue. But dnt know how to tackle this one. Can any body guide me? Thanx in advance.

**Edit(Explanation)**

like a chat window in **Viber** or **Whats App**, i have a `EditText` at the bottom, a `ListView` in the center and an `ActionBar` at the top. when i clicked the `EditText` , the background image shrinks/squeeze. I used `adjustPan` to overcome this. Its fine. But now, when the soft Keyboard appears, it hides the `ActionBar/TitleBar`.

Comment: please elaborate your question??

Comment: facing the similar problem...and still trying to figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use adjustResize instead of adjustPan. The framework will always try to keep the focused element on-screen by scrolling any parent views if necessary.

If your EditText field is not nested in some sort of scrolling container such as a ScrollView then your layout may be too tall to completely display when the keyboard resizes your activity. Try wrapping your form's layout in a ScrollView. This will also allow your app's content to scroll if it is running on a smaller screen device where it may have similar issues.

Comment: When i use `adjustResize` it shrinks the background image.

Comment: my previous problem was like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287473/android-soft-keyboard-resizes-background-image

Comment: In Manifest

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"

In XMl

Dont Set any background here.And keep your view under ScrollView

In Java

You need to set the background to window:

getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.bg_wood) ;

Comment: You can also try android:scaleType="matrix" in your background imageview