# Android keyboard not open over layout

Tags: android

I have an edittext at the bottom of my chat view. When the soft keyboard opens, it pushes the whole view up, so it sits atop the keyboard which stretch background image. I actually want it to open keyboard over backgournd and shifts edittext up.

Anyone else run into this issue? Know how to fix it?

Comment: what u exactly mean ? it looks like you want to shift edittext to top but not entire view ??

Comment: yes you are right, i want this

Answer (score 0):

Add this in ur manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

For Example :
Modify ur manifest like this

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.admob.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
```

This will work .. **Now The Entire layout  will be shifted Up** . .But If u add ur image as background image it will not be shifted.

EX: `android:background="@drawable/background"`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/xxx"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/background">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now the edittext and the other views will be shifted but not the image

Comment: I tried this android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize", its works but The Entire layout will be shifted Up and I am using Linearlayout

Comment: How did you add ur image ? Whether its background image or Imageview ?

Comment: Its backgound image of linearlayout.

Comment: Can u post screenshots Before Shifting up and after shifting up ?

Comment: Same problem here..Try that solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287473/android-soft-keyboard-resizes-background-image

Comment: Yes.  Before shifting https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A242370F52E73382!193&authkey=!AHuMt_5Hx0KZsVc&v=3&ithint=photo%2c.jpg   After shifting- https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A242370F52E73382!192&authkey=!AOiphMDPu-ZrDOc&v=3&ithint=photo%2c.jpg

Comment: Have u tried this ? Same problem here..Try that solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287473/android-soft-keyboard-resizes-background-image

Comment: Yes i tried this also not working but i solved my issue. Thanks