# Software keyboard resizes background image on Android app in titanium appcelerator

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

Whenever the software keyboard appears, it resizes the background image.

See screen shot here in this question link.

[Software keyboard resizes background image on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287473/software-keyboard-resizes-background-image-on-android)

This question was for android and i want to implement in Titanium.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the [windowSoftInputMode](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-windowSoftInputMode) property in your window.

Generally speaking, you can assign to this property any combination of two types of constants: visibility states (ALWAYS_HIDDEN, ALWAYS_VISIBLE, HIDDEN, UNSPECIFIED or VISIBLE) and adjustment options (PAN, RESIZE or UNSPECIFIED).

In your case you can combine **SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE** and **SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN**.
Just make few changes in your .tss file:

```
"#yourWindowID": {
    ...
    windowSoftInputMode: Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE | Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN
    ...
}
```

You can find more information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#softInputMode).

Comment: I was using that but using this my app action bar hides.