# Custom actionbar is scaled when keyboard appears in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-custom-view, custom-view

I have a layout which contain an actionbar and scrollview holding some edittexts. When I click on edittext, keyboard appears and actionbar is scaled vertically. How can I make actionbar not be scaled. I added in manifest: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize". I just wanna resize scrollview. I don't use "adjustPan" because my layout will be pushed upwards. Thank you for your help.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutBehind"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="11"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:isScrollContainer="false" >

            <include layout="@layout/actionbar" >
            </include>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#F0F0F0"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/li2"
                android:isScrollContainer="false" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        style="@style/ln_inserttext"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent" >
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                            style="@style/tv_insert_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/Name" />

                        <com.decopcard.layout.EditTextDone
                            android:id="@+id/edt_name"
                            style="@style/edt_insert_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/edittext_backgrounf"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                            android:gravity="top"
                            android:lines="2"
                            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                            android:scrollbars="vertical"
                            android:text="@string/TextDefaultName"
                            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_name_divide"
                            style="@style/rl_package2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                            android:background="#F0ECE0" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_phonetic"
                            style="@style/tv_insert_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/Phonetic" />

                        <com.decopcard.layout.EditTextDone
                            android:id="@+id/edt_phone_tic"
                            style="@style/edt_insert_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/edittext_backgrounf"
                            android:gravity="top"
                            android:lines="2"
                            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                            android:scrollbars="vertical"
                            android:text="@string/TextDefaultName"
                            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        style="@style/custom_dialog_remainpoint_1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_zip"
                            style="@style/tv_insert_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/Zip" />

                        <com.decopcard.layout.EditTextDone
                            android:id="@+id/edt_zip"
                            style="@style/edt_insert_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/edittext_backgrounf"
                            android:gravity="top"
                            android:lines="2"
                            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                            android:scrollbars="vertical"
                            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_zip_divide"
                            style="@style/tv_insert_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                            android:background="#F0ECE0" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_address"
                            style="@style/tv_inserttext_2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/Address" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edt_address"
                            style="@style/edt_insert_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/edittext_backgrounf"
                            android:gravity="top"
                            android:lines="3"
                            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                            android:scrollbars="vertical"
                            android:text="@string/TextDefaultAddress"
                            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_address_divide"
                            style="@style/tv_insert_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                            android:background="#F0ECE0" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_phone_number"
                            style="@style/rl_package2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/PhoneNumber" />

                        <com.decopcard.layout.EditTextDone
                            android:id="@+id/edt_phone_number"
                            style="@style/edt_insert_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/edittext_backgrounf"
                            android:gravity="top"
                            android:lines="2"
                            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                            android:scrollbars="vertical"
                            android:text="@string/TextDefaultPhoneNumber"
                            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        style="@style/custom_dialog_remainpoint_1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_mail"
                            style="@style/tv_insert_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/MailAddress" />

                        <com.decopcard.layout.EditTextDone
                            android:id="@+id/edt_mail"
                            style="@style/edt_insert_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/edittext_backgrounf"
                            android:gravity="top"
                            android:lines="2"
                            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                            android:scrollbars="vertical"
                            android:text="@string/TextDefaultMailAddress"
                            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_divide"
                            style="@style/rl_package2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                            android:background="#F0ECE0" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_url"
                            style="@style/tv_insert_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/Url" />

                        <com.decopcard.layout.EditTextDone
                            android:id="@+id/edt_url"
                            style="@style/edt_insert_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/edittext_backgrounf"
                            android:gravity="top"
                            android:lines="2"
                            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                            android:scrollbars="vertical"
                            android:text="@string/TextDefaultUrl"
                            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        style="@style/custom_dialog_remainpoint_1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_company"
                            style="@style/tv_insert_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/Company" />

                        <com.decopcard.layout.EditTextDone
                            android:id="@+id/edt_company"
                            style="@style/edt_insert_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/edittext_backgrounf"
                            android:gravity="top"
                            android:lines="2"
                            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                            android:scrollbars="vertical"
                            android:text="@string/TextDefaultCompany"
                            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_company_divide"
                            style="@style/rl_package2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                            android:background="#F0ECE0" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_position"
                            style="@style/tv_insert_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/CompanyPosition" />

                        <com.decopcard.layout.EditTextDone
                            android:id="@+id/edt_position"
                            style="@style/edt_insert_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/edittext_backgrounf"
                            android:gravity="top"
                            android:lines="2"
                            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                            android:scrollbars="vertical"
                            android:text="@string/TextDefaultCompanyPosition"
                            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        style="@style/custom_dialog_remainpoint_1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_opening"
                            style="@style/tv_insert_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/OpeningHours" />

                        <com.decopcard.layout.EditTextDone
                            android:id="@+id/edt_open"
                            style="@style/edt_insert_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/edittext_backgrounf"
                            android:gravity="top"
                            android:lines="2"
                            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                            android:scrollbars="vertical"
                            android:text="@string/TextDefaultOpeningHours"
                            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        style="@style/custom_dialog_remainpoint_1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/li2"
                style="@style/ln_shop2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/liner_history"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/hot"
                            android:visibility="invisible" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_middle"
                            style="@style/text_shop2_bellow"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Hot"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:visibility="invisible" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/liner_middle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_middle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/btn_contact_inserttext" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </FrameLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/liner_search"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Its seems like same problem as in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287473/software-keyboard-resizes-background-image-on-android)

Comment: I read the linked article, but it didn't help. Thank you. Here I don't want the actionbar to be scaled. It looks like whenever keyboard appears, actionbar will wrap_content.