# EditText input change background layout (Fragment)

Tags: layout, background, android-edittext

*Fragment background layout is shrinking when the virtual keyboard is display on an editText input; how can I fix this.*

```
       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/age"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginLeft="79dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="79dp"
           android:digits=" 0123456789"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:hint="..."
           android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />
```

Comment: Try this in manifest for respective activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"

Comment: **Try this may help** [Software keyboard resizes background image on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287473/software-keyboard-resizes-background-image-on-android)

Comment: @Abhishek It worked Thank you!!